# how to add add Module "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310" in CamelTestSupport

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel, camel-test

I am creating a test that extends of CamelTestSupport. I am using Apache Camel 3.10. I have tried to set JavaTimeModule() in the test inside the createRouteBuilder, with

```
  public ObjectMapper produceObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    objectMapper.registerModule(new VavrModule());
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    return objectMapper;
  }
  
  @BeforeEach
  void initTest() {
    this.objectMapper = new ObjectMapperConfiguration().produceObjectMapper();
  }  

  @Override
  protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
    InputRoute inputRoute = new InputRoute("direct:start","direct:dlq");
    inputRoute.setContext(this.context);
    inputRoute.bindToRegistry("platformTransactionManager", platformTransactionManager);
    inputRoute.bindToRegistry("notificationRepository", notificationRepository);
    inputRoute.bindToRegistry("objectMapperJackson",objectMapper);

    return inputRoute;
  }
```

this object Mapper
but I get this error:

> Java 8 date/time type `java.time.ZonedDateTime` not supported by
> default: add Module
> "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310" to enable
> handling

This ZoneDateTime is working in the project, also in the SpringBootTest. But not in the CamelTestSupport test. Any idea?

Comment: What is `InputRoute`? For which component do you use your custom `ObjectMapper`?

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example